# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/Content

Tags: java, jdom-2

I have a small code using jdom that creates a very simple xml, but when I try to run it after compiling the classes, outputs the error in the title `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/Content`

I have the jdom.jar file in the same directory as the java file. To compile the classes I used `javac -cp "jdom.jar" -d . *.java` and then `java packagename.classname` to execute it.

This is the code, even tho I'm pretty sure it is not needed

```
package jtest;
import java.io.*;
import org.jdom2.*;
import org.jdom2.input.*;
import org.jdom2.output.*;
public class JDomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Element concesionario = new Element("concesionario");
            Document doc = new Document(concesionario);

            Element coches = new Element("coches");

            Element coche = new Element("coche");

            Element matricula = new Element("matricula");
            matricula.setText("1111AAA");

            Element marca = new Element("marca");
            marca.setText("AUDI");

            Element precio = new Element("precio");
            precio.setText("30000");

            coche.addContent(matricula);
            coche.addContent(marca);
            coche.addContent(precio);

            coches.addContent(coche);

            coche = new Element("coche");

            matricula = new Element("matricula");
            matricula.setText("2222BBB");

            marca = new Element("marca");
            marca.setText("SEAT");

            precio = new Element("precio");
            precio.setText("10000");

            coche.addContent(matricula);
            coche.addContent(marca);
            coche.addContent(precio);

            coches.addContent(coche);

            coche = new Element("coche");

            matricula = new Element("matricula");
            matricula.setText("3333CCC");

            marca = new Element("marca");
            marca.setText("BMW");

            precio = new Element("precio");
            precio.setText("20000");

            coche.addContent(matricula);

            coche.addContent(marca);
            coche.addContent(precio);

            coches.addContent(coche);

            coche = new Element("coche");

            matricula = new Element("matricula");
            matricula.setText("4444DDD");

            marca = new Element("marca");
            marca.setText("TOYOTA");

            precio = new Element("precio");
            precio.setText("10000");

            coche.addContent(matricula);
            coche.addContent(marca);
            coche.addContent(precio);
            coches.addContent(coche);

            XMLOutputter xml = new XMLOutputter();
            xml.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xml.output(doc, new FileWriter("text.xml"));

        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

---

I'm using Java 11 on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using just `java packagename.classname` *jdom.jar* will **not** be in your classpath.
You will have to specify your full classpath using `-cp` or `--classpath`, e.g.

`java -cp "./jdom.jar:./" packagename.classname`

Note: on Linux the separator is `:` while on Windows it is `;`

Comment: Thanks, before this I already tried using `java -cp "jdom.jar" packagename.classname` which is kinda similar but ofc didn't work